# Applying for Chinese visa while traveling

Tags: visas, china, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian living in the US. I am leaving for Central and South America for 6 months in October. I come back on April 4th and am supposed to leave for China on April 11th. I thought I would apply for my Chinese visa before I go, but from what I have read, I cannot apply more than 3 months before my trip.  Clearly I cannot apply while I am traveling. I live in Seattle and I would have to mail my passport since we do not have a local office.

Does anyone have any kind of solution for me?

Comment: Have you ever had a visa for Chna before?

Answer (score 5):

1. Courier your passport to a friend or agent at home and have them apply for you. This is best. If you have no idea who to work with I would Google the words chinese visa courier toronto and then look for reviews for whatever companies I find.
2. Try every Chinese Consulate you come close to, who knows, one might grant you a visa.

Edit: Before leaving get a [certified true copy of Canadian travel document](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/passport/forms/pdf/pptc516-eng.pdf) so you have something at least when you are without your passport. While returning to Canada with just that might be difficult at least it's not impossible.

Comment: 1 means that OP will be in a foreign country without her passport.  Even assuming she doesn't need to cross any borders during that time or return home unexpectedly, do you think that's advisable?

Comment: @NateEldredge added something.

Answer (score 2):

Why not apply for a ten year multi-entry visa before you go.  Sure it costs more money, but you avoid the headaches you are facing right now.  And can return to China in the future without applying for new visas.

You can apply for it in the US as long as you can document that you are living here with the proper visas and meet all other requirements.  Or send it by courier to a China visa service in Canada and have them do it in your homeland.